# Setting Timeout On HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class library that I'm porting to a Windows 8 Store Class Library.
One of the methods uses the now not supported synchronous HttpWebRequest.
I need to keep the method synchronous as the Async work has been done in the applications not the library and changing it would take a great deal of effort.
I've changed it to a Synchronous task with IAsyncresult but I'm not sure how to set the request timeout using this code. Can someone help?
Also can anyone see any other issues I may encounter with this code?

```
//Create Web Request
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
IAsyncResult asyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

if (asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5 * 1000))
{
    //Get Response
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult) as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        if (request.HaveResponse && response != null)
        {
            using (Stream reader = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                result = XDocument.Load(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    request.Abort();
}
```

UPDATE: I've added a waithandle to the request and if it times out I abort the httpwebrequest. Does this take care of any threads started by HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
if(false == request.GetResponseAsync().Wait(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2.0)))
{
    Trace.WriteLine("timeout");
    return;
}
//...
```

Now keep in mind, this is simply the timeout to wait on the asynchronous operation.  To specifically deal with a timeout on the response/requeststream operation, see `HttpWebRequest.Timeout`.

You don't have to use `async`/`await` with `*Async` methods.  They simply return a `Task<T>` object that you can work with and use methods like `Wait`, `ContinueWith`, etc...  Much easier than dealing with the `Begin`/`End` (APM pattern)...

FWIW the `*Async` pattern is called the *Task Asynchronous Pattern* (TAP).  It seems to be the recommended pattern now, replacing the *Asynchronous Programming Model* (APM, `Begin`/`End`) and *Event-based Asynchronous Pattern* (EPM, `Completed`, `CancelAsync`, etc...).

Comment: Thanks Peter, I want to try and use something that's supported in .net 4 if possible so the code can be shared between the old and new applications using this library, although I could use directives if pushed. I've updated my post with a request.abort.  Do you know if that will kill the thread created by the request?

Comment: Ahh, okay.  I saw Windows 8 Store Application and assumed you were targeting 4.5...  You can wrap the begin/end with `TaskFactory.FromAsync` to get it to create Task<T> for you...